# Changing which target is built and run

Tags: xcode5, target

I am using Xcode 5 and I have 2 targets inside of a project. I can't seem to change which target is built and run, as the first one is always chosen when I click run. Am I missing something? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Use the Scheme menu to choose the target to build and run. The Scheme menu is next to the Run and Stop buttons in the project window toolbar. Clicking the target in the Scheme menu (CocoaAppTest in the screenshot) opens a menu. Choose the other target to build and run that target.

[image]

If you don't get a choice of targets in the menu, choose Manage Schemes. Click the Autocreate Schemes Now button to create a scheme for the second target. Use that scheme to build and run the second target.